# Filtering Negative values less than certain value in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two columns "Esc1" and "Esc2". I want to apply a "where" condition such that if the difference between esc1 and esc2 is less than -30 then "yes less than -30" else "No".

I used the following code,

```
np.where((df['Esc1']-df['Esc2']<-30),"yes less than -30","No")
```

But the above result considered even difference such as -4 or -5 as "yes less than -30"

Comment: Cannot verify, for me working well. Is possible add some sample data which failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Esc1'] = np.arange(10)
df['Esc2'] = np.arange(10, 50, 4)
df['diff'] = df['Esc1'] - df['Esc2']
pd.cut(df['diff'], bins=[-np.inf, -30, np.inf], labels=['yes less than -30', 'no'])
```